# VBA Chart Macro Range Using Union - Error

Tags: excel, vba, charts, union

I am trying to create a scatter chart using a macro that uses data in columns that are not adjacent. Once that is working, I would like to add more series to the chart, stepping across columns, but I can't get the first part to work. This is my code:

```
Sub Better_Chart()
   Dim chtChart As Chart
   Dim X As Integer
   Dim Y As Integer
   Dim Z As Integer

   'For X = Range("E1").Column To Range("K1").Column Step 6

    X = Range("E1").Column
    Z = Range("C1").Column
    Cells(14, X).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    If Range("E14") <> Empty Then
    Y = Selection.Rows.Count + 13
    End If

 'Create a new chart.

 Set chtChart = Charts.Add
 Set chtChart = chtChart.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Yield Data")
 With chtChart

 '.Name = ""

 .ChartType = xlXYScatter
 'Link to the source data range.
' .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Yield Data").Range(Cells(14, Z), Cells(Y, X)),
 .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Yield Data").Union(Range(Cells(14, X), Cells(Y, X)), Range(Cells(14, Z), Cells(Y, Z))), _
 PlotBy:=xlColumns

' Next Y

 'Next X

 .HasTitle = True
 .ChartTitle.Text = Range("H3")
 .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
 .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = Range("H5")
 .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
 .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = Range("H7")

 End With

End Sub
```

I get a debug error on the setSourceDate line. However, this code works perfectly, in that it selects the exact data I want to graph:

```
Public Sub Test_Union()
   Dim chtChart As Chart
   Dim X As Integer
   Dim Y As Integer
   Dim Z As Integer

   'For X = Range("E1").Column To Range("K1").Column Step 6
    X = Range("E1").Column
    Z = Range("C1").Column
    Cells(14, X).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

    If Range("E14") <> Empty Then
    Y = Selection.Rows.Count + 13
    End If

    'Range(Cells(14, Z), Cells(Y, X)).Select
     Union(Range(Cells(14, Z), Cells(Y, Z)), Range(Cells(14, X), Cells(Y, X))).Select
    'Range(Cells(14, Z), Cells(Y, X)).Select

' Next Y

 'Next X  

End Sub
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> .SetSourceData Sheets("Yield Data").Union(Range(Cells(14, X), ...
> ```

If `Sheets("Yield Data")` isn't the `ActiveSheet`, then all these unqualified `Range` and `Cells` calls inside that `Union-from-a-very-specific-sheet` call are trying to union ranges from different worksheets, which blows up with error 1004.

The best solution is to qualify *all* references to the sheet you mean to be working with:

```
Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Yield Data")
.SetSourceData sh.Union(sh.Range(sh.Cells(14, X), ...
```

Another "solution" (work-around, really) would be to *make* that sheet the `ActiveSheet`:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Yield Data").Activate
.SetSourceData Union(Range(Cells(14, X), ...
```

But to write reliable code, you really should be avoiding `Select` and `Activate`, so go with properly-qualified `Worksheet` member calls - including with your "works fine" code, which is also implicitly referring to whatever the `ActiveSheet` is, but only involves that sheet.